# Bottle Displays Old Template?

Tags: python, bottle

I made a first draft of a template, called `batch.tpl`. I have updated it, however, the old template still displays. I have shut off the controller script and turned it back on multiple times. I have removed everything from the template except for the following:

`cat views/batch.tpl`

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
        <TITLE> Batch Manager </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    THIS ISN'T DISPLAYING IN BROWSER
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Yet that will not show, just the old template.

Here is my controller:

`cat brew_bottle.py`

```
    from bottle import route, run, template, debug, post, request
import MySQLdb
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime


@route('/batch')
def batch():
    con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pi', 'brew')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    batch_sql = "SELECT name, material, start_date, active, end_begin_date, end_end_date, min_temp, max_temp FROM batch WHERE active='Y'"
    cursor.execute(batch_sql)
    batches = cursor.fetchall()
    return template('batch', batches=batches)
#...
debug(True)
run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080', reloader=True)
```

However, when I go to `http://<hostname>:8080/batch`, I see the old template that I had wrote:

[image]

I am sure I am missing something easy. What is it?

I created a new directory and moved everything to it. Then when I start the python script, I am able to see the correct page. But the python script in the old directory displays the old template?

Comment: Stopping and starting the bottle server helps? I'm  just wondering if it is a `reloader` issue.

Comment: @alecxe No, stopping and restarting the bottle server doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bottle docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#auto-reloading), auto reloading (`reloading`) is only triggered by changes to module files.

> Changes in template files will not trigger a reload. Please use debug
>   mode to deactivate template caching.

Turn on [Bottle's debug mode](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#debug-mode) this way:

```
bottle.debug(True)
```

> Here is an incomplete list of things that change in debug mode:
>
> The default error page shows a traceback. Templates are not cached.
>   Plugins are applied immediately. Just make sure not to use the debug
>   mode on a production server.

---

N.B., I see that someone already asked you whether restarting the server caused the updated template to appear, and that you indicated that it did not.  That's highly suspicious.  In any case, try fixing the problem above and see whether that solves your problem.  Good luck!